# sql alchemy python query query.first() _and

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am modifying some code I did not write.  The problem with this code is that tracking numbers have started to recycle with the carrier.  So for a given tracking number there may be two sometimes 3 rows in the database.  This code apparently finds the first record in the query which in our case is the 'oldest created date'.

So I would like to understand how to change this to one of the  2 options I am thinking so the program only pulls the most recent tracking number.

1. Retrieve the last record of the query and place it in manifest variable.
2. use an 'AND' on the query filter.  I have a created_date column that I can say:
   if tracking number = exception tracking number AND created date > 1/1/20011.

So if someone could provide the code that does #1 and #2 I would be grateful.

```
query = session.query(database.Manifest)
query = query.filter(database.Manifest.tracking_number==exception.TrackingNumber)

manifest = query.first()
```

I thought for number 2, the statement could be:

```
query = query.filter(_and(database.Manifest.tracking_number==exception.TrackingNumber, 
database.Manifest.created_date > '2011-01-01'))
```

ok?

Comment: Just a note ... as a general rule, if a query has no explicit `order by` clause then you can't expect rows to be returned in any particular order at all.  It will return them in whatever the query optimiser decides is the quickest way.

Answer (score 4):

Your first option cannot be done accurately unless you have a column, like an identity, that helps you understand the order in which rows were put into the table.  (EDIT: From your attached comments it seems you have a created_at field ...)

So a query would be

```
query = (session.query(database.Manifest)
         .filter_by(tracking_number=exception.TrackingNumber)
         .order_by(desc(database.Manifest.created_at)))   
manifest = query.first()
```

If you don't, then you must rely on your database simply returning rows in the order they were first inserted by magic, then you will need to grab all of them and take the last one

```
query = (session.query(database.Manifest)
         .filter_by(tracking_number=exception.TrackingNumber))
manifest = query.all()[-1]
```

And frankly, you can't rely on your database to do that ... it will generally return them in whatever it assesses to be the fastest available way.

As for the second option you ask for, it would just be

```
query = (session.query(database.Manifest)
         .filter_by(tracking_number=exception.TrackingNumber)
         .filter(database.Manifest.date > datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)))

manifest = query.first()
```

Comment: @user990726 these are the options which you can apply. If you can give exact table structure then you might be get perfect answer without multiple choices.

Comment: Thank you! Just one clarification.  This is my date field in the dbase using mySql:      created_at       timestamp  so does the datetime.date format above work correctly with that scenario?  thx.

Comment: would this also work?  query = query.filter(_and(database.Manifest.tracking_number==exception.TrackingNumber, database.Manifest.created_date > '2011-01-01'))

ok?

Comment: @user990726 It will work if you use `and_` rather than `_and`

Comment: @Donkopotamus just one more clarification on your answer.  It is for sure = and not == in the filter_by statement for the tracking numbers.  correct?  thx

Comment: @user990726 Please read the manual as to the difference between filter_by and filter.